# Denying direct access to configuration files

Tags: php, .htaccess, web, config

I'd like to know how i can go about denying direct web access to configuration files of application whilst allowing php to access them.

I know most answers would suggest to put the includes outside the public_html directory. But I really don't think it's that efficient.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you think it's not "that" efficient? What if you accidentally disable .htaccess in apache? Your config files will get exposed without you ever knowing.

Comment: I'm concerned about the file organizing when distributing the code. Maybe its because im new to this. Do you put your app files inside a public_html alongside an includes directory and distribute it?

Comment: No, you just put your public web-accessable files in public_html

Comment: Maybe i wasn't clear enough. People suggest to put the config files outside the public web directory. If i choose this method, it'd be a hassle to distribute the application, no? Provided some users find it a troublesome to go up setting up an application to get simple things done.

Comment: Why would it be a hassle to distribute it? What difference does it make?

Comment: Because i cannot judge the directory organizing that another person would be using.

Answer (score 1):

PHP just uses the file system to access files where web users usually go through apache and that verifies a .htaccess file. So just place that file that contains `deny from all` into that directory and voilla.

Comment: Thanks. But just looking for an alternative as .htaccess can be disabled.

Comment: Define a constant in your index.php and if that constant is not defined in your include do a `header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');exit;` However check if your headers are already send though otherwise it is no use.

Comment: This is pretty intelligent. But provided my configurations files are in json format, rather than being php files, i guess i wont be able to use this. Other than write php scripts that serve json.

Comment: you could then cache your json files to an php array and filter allowed pages from there. Sure, might be a hassle but you're making it pretty difficult on yourself already ;)